# change onClick url via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I do show different images via the browser url in javascript, as the image change the onClick link has to change too.
Currently my HTML image look like:

```
<img id="adImage" src="" style="width: 100%; cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.open('http://google.de', '_blank');">
```

So i want to change the `http://google.de` into something else 
For the images i do

```
image.src = "http://imaimagelink.de/image.png";
```

is there a way to change the window.open url in the same way?

Comment: `So i want to change the http://google.de into something else`  what is that something else?? is it same as the image source? if not then what and how do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a global variable to hold the reference.
example:

```
<script>
  var url = "google.nl";

  function changeUrl(tarurl){
     url = tarurl;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , sure you can.

```
document.getElementById("adImage").onclick=function(){window.open('http://yournewurl.com', '_blank');};
```